# Can't connect to wireless networks Intel Wireless

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm a new Linux user and I cannot add or edit any network connections, nor is the system detecting any wireless networks.
When I try to access additional hardware from system, it doesn't even open, So I'm stuck.

```
lspci | grep -i wireless 
06:0a.0 Network controller:
Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2]
 Network connection (rev 05)

lspci -n -s 06:0a.0
8086:4220.
```

I dont know if that info was relevant but any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your wireless card is just disabled. Try typing the following into terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```